# PHP error_reporting to suppress notices and warnings

Tags: php, wordpress, error-reporting

I have this set in `php.ini`:

`error_reporting = E_ALL ^ E_WARNING ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_DEPRECATED ^ E_STRICT`

Yet I'm still seeing things like this:

`Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in /var/www/html/web/wp-content/plugins/folders/includes/types.php on line 188`

I would like to suppress all notices and warnings.

Comment: What does the manual say about it?

Comment: I've tried the suggestions in the manual (which uses slightly different syntax) but it produces the same result

Comment: Did you try? `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);`

Comment: You should probably tag it with WordPress tag. It could be relevant.

Comment: On `wp-config.php` set `define('WP_DEBUG', false);` show hide those warning

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile perfect, thanks. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/103043/126589 so debug mode will override any previously error reporting

Answer (score 0):

To suppress only notices and warnings set
`error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_WARNINGS & ~E_NOTICE`

Answer (score -1):

try adding this line to the beginning of your php script, that will hide all the errors.

```
<?php error_reporting(0);
```

Comment: I'm using WordPress so there are thousands of files

Comment: are you in local or hosting?